# Abstract class mock is null

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I have some classes

Property class

```
public abstract class Property {
    public Property() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

ParentClass using Property

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    @Getter
    protected Property property;

    public ParentClass(Property property) {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

Class which will be under the test

```
public class TargetClass extends ParentClass {
    public class TargetClass (Property property) {
        super(property);
    }
}
```

Finally I have TargetClassTest for testing Target class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TargetClass.class, ParentClass.class, Property.class})

public class TargetClassTest {
    @Mock
    private Property property;
    @InjectMocks
    private TargetClass target;

    @Test
    public void start() {
        target = new TargetClass(property);
    }
}
```

I am using PowerMock and Junit4

Why property is null, when I am initializing the instance of TargetClass?

Dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: you are aware you can't  instantiate abstract classes?

Comment: Why do you have `@InjectMocks targetClass` and at the same time `new TargetClass(…)`?

Comment: @Stultuske Property will be used in test further and it shouldn't be null

Comment: @knittl Is "new TargetClass(…)" unneccessary?

Comment: Well, at least one of them is. You cannot have 2 object instance in the same variable. The assignment will overwrite the value that was assigned by the runner; so `@InjectMocks` is pretty much useless. But as always: it depends on your use-case.

Comment: @PrintScreenSys that doesn't automatically mean you can instantiate an abstract class. But knittl is right, your setup is incorrect.

Comment: I tried to remove InjectMocks annotation, but property is null

Comment: @PrintScreenSys no, remove the = new( .... ) instead

Comment: I am rewriting test from Mockto to PowerMock, and in this test property wasn't null

Comment: @Stultuske ok, but now the instance of TargetClass is null

Comment: do you know how PowerMock works?
https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock?fbclid=IwAR2pL75xB8nqOnX88tJm-cIESuQPhI3QWecnmswnfejkJn-VDErwrdEv040